# raise OSError('No translation files found for default language %s.' % settings.LANGUAGE_CODE) Ubuntu Django

Tags: django, ubuntu

I've created another language (IN-te) on Django application, it is working perfectly fine on my dev machine (MacOS) but when I host it to Ubuntu server, it is giving me following error

> raise OSError('No translation files found for default language %s.' %
> settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

> OSError: No translation files found for
> default language IN-te.

I'm able to process `.po` files

[image]

I have `local` folder with all necessary files

[image]

what might be issue here?